# Prompt User to Loop

Tags: c++

I have created a Prompt User to Loop to restart the program however when I type anything including "y" it just goes prompts me with "Press any key to continue . . . " and then closes. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Multiple1 = 0;
    int Multiple2 = 0;

    char again = 'Y';

    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
    {

        int Multiple1 = 0;
        int Multiple2 = 0;
        cout << "Input your first Multiple: " << endl;
        cin >> Multiple1;
        cout << "Your First Multiple is: " << Multiple1 << endl;

        cout << "Input your second Multiple: " << endl;
        cin >> Multiple2;

        cout << "Your Second Multiple is: " << Multiple2 << endl;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % Multiple1 == 0 && i % Multiple2 == 0)
                cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
            else
                if (i % Multiple1 == 0)
                    cout << "Fizz" << endl;
                else
                    if (i % Multiple2 == 0)
                        cout << "Buzz" << endl;
                    else cout << i << endl;


        }

        {
            cout << "Restart? (y/n) ";
            cin >> again;



        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you.﻿

This is my first project and I am completely new to coding so I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return 0` is misplaced, it should be outside the while loop.

And you shouldn't put a bracket `{}` around your `cin >> again`.

```
    { // this bracket doesn't needed
        cout << "Restart? (y/n) ";
        cin >> again;



    }
```

Just use bracket when it needed e.g. in `for, if, function, etc`. It will not make a compile error. But I think it makes you misread and think the while loop was closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Multiple1 = 0;
    int Multiple2 = 0;

    char again = 'Y';

    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
    {

        int Multiple1 = 0;
        int Multiple2 = 0;
        cout << "Input your first Multiple: " << endl;
        cin >> Multiple1;
        cout << "Your First Multiple is: " << Multiple1 << endl;

        cout << "Input your second Multiple: " << endl;
        cin >> Multiple2;

        cout << "Your Second Multiple is: " << Multiple2 << endl;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % Multiple1 == 0 && i % Multiple2 == 0)
                cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
            else
                if (i % Multiple1 == 0)
                    cout << "Fizz" << endl;
                else
                    if (i % Multiple2 == 0)
                        cout << "Buzz" << endl;
                    else cout << i << endl;


        }

        { //This bracket doesn't need.
            cout << "Restart? (y/n) ";
            cin >> again;
            continue;
        } // This bracket doesn't need.
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```